# .webm recorder like LICEcap

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I've used [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for a few years and always recorded pixel art with it with only a few colours. I started recording other 'stuff' with more colours lately but the quality was very bad.

[Example http://desu.animekoko.ga/img/akamegagif.gif](http://desu.animekoko.ga/img/akamegagif.gif)
<sup>Some example of that recording</sup>

I heard good things about [`.webm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) and I see it used more frequently. Is there anything like LICEcap (selecting a part of the screen and just start/stop recording) which makes `.webm`?

**Requirements:**

- lets you select a part of the screen to record
- saves in [`.webm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) format
- runs on Windows
- has no watermark

Comment: Hi, could you edit your post to actually contain the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [ActivePresenter](http://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/free-edition/)

The free version has all the features (and even more) you want:

- free
- no watermark for WebM (*)
- .webm output
- runs on Windows
- selectable portion of screen
- add annotations
- add captions
- easy to use
- use microphone

To make video like in below screenshot: Full Motion Recording
To make .webm: Export>Video
[image]

(*)
From [their homepage](http://atomisystems.com/download/): export to formats other then WMV, AVI, MPEG4, WebM will have a watermark. 
Activating with a license key will remove the watermark on appropriate outputs.

Comment: Important to note, the basic version is [only free **for non-commercial use**](http://atomisystems.com/activepresenter-free-eula/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Screenpresso](http://www.screenpresso.com/)

Screenpresso is a lightweight Windows app for screen capture using screenshots or HD video.

- It allows you to select a region on the screen to capture. It also uses a magnifier for pixel-level accuracy
- Saves in `.webm` format, among others (see image below)
- Runs on Windows

The downside is that it attaches a watermark to the corner of each video if you use the free version.

[image]

Comment: I've used it but the webm it made were terribly slow and a watermark isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

[**WebMCam**](https://github.com/TheTarkus/WebMCam/)

Capture frames in real-time and save them as WebM.

[image: WebMCam Interface]

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to conform to the [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/). You should have some experience using the software. What exactly did you like about it, and what did you not like as much? How does the software match each requirement in the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[**ShareX**](https://getsharex.com)

[image: ShareX screenshot]

- Open source
- No watermark
- Records to `.webm` (need to change in settings as default is `.mp4`)
- Runs on Windows

Furthermore

- Supports display scaling
- Take screenshots
- Capture custom areas, windows
- Records to `.gif`, and multiple video formats (encodes using FFmpeg)
- Annotation tools
- Can upload to multiple destinations, such as imgur, twitter, dropbox, youtube...