# Simple software for recording the screen for educational shorties

Tags: windows-8, screen-recording

I can google up a whole bunch different applications but I have no means to test them all. The recommendations I've found are vague and there's no clear "good one". I'm looking for something like Paint.NET or Notepad++ but for creating short movies.

The functionality needs only to include the simplest things like marking up parts of the screen, pointing out a section and such.
The price should be in the budget segment, preferably fairly close to or exactly at zero. :)

The questions asked were more about Mac and Linux, while I'll be Windows-ing all the way.

Is there any widely used application for that?

Comment: You might wish to take a look into the answers to [.webm recorder like LICEcap](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13595/185), which match your question.